# JavaScript - error with inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to use inheritance, but I'm stuck. I'm getting an error and don't know what I'm doing wrong. All examples I see online don't pass objects into their constructors, so I'm not sure what I should be doing. Here is a dumbed down example -

```
function Automobile(obj){
    this.name = obj.name;
    this.model = obj.model;
}

Automobile.prototype = {
    getName: function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    getModel: function(){
        console.log(this.model);
    }
}

var bmw = new Automobile({
    name: 'BMW',
    model: 'm5'
})

bmw.getName();
bmw.getModel();


function Truck(obj){
    this.cabSize = obj.cabSize
}

Truck.prototype = new Automobile();
Truck.prototype = {
    getCabSize: function(){
        console.log(this.cabSize);
    }
}

var fordF150 = new Truck({
    name: 'Ford',
    model: 'F150'
})

//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined test.js:2
//Automobile test.js:2
//(anonymous function)
```

Comment: You haven't passed an object when you called `Truck.prototype = new Automobile();` its expecting the first parameter to be an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring at `Truck.prototype = new Automobile();`. You are not passing obj, which `Automobile` expects.

To avoid this try `Truck.prototype = Object.create(Automobile.prototype)`

After that use

```
Truck.prototype.getCabSite = function(){
}
```

so that you don't overwrite the inherited properties from Automobile.

Comment: Is there any way that I can do this and keep the Truck.prototype = {...} to add new methods in? Not a huge deal, I just prefer to add prototypes that way.

Comment: You can do `Truck.prototype.WhateverYouWantToAdd = function(){}` over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Truck.prototype = {
    getCabSize: function(){
        console.log(this.cabSize);
    }
}
```

try this:

```
Truck.prototype.getCabSite = function(){


}

Truck.prototype.constructor = Truck; //this will insure the appropriate constructor is called
```

that way you don't delete get rid of the automobile protoype

Comment: Thanks onzur. I somehow would like to keep the Truck.prototype = {} formatting so I can add more methods in that manner. Not sure how I can set the Truck to inherit Automobile and still do that? At any rate though, I still get the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error with this update.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can use `$.extend()` to merge objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. You changed "prototype" of Truck -> you can't inherit.

   Truck.prototype = new Automobile();
   Truck.prototype = {
                  getCabSize: function(){
                   console.log(this.cabSize);
               }
   }; // Change prototype of Truck

   You can repair

   **Truck.prototype.getCabSize = function(){};**

1 Example about the change of prototype, i write some line of code use your Automobile function

```
function Automobile(obj){
    this.name = obj.name;
    this.model = obj.model;
}

Automobile.prototype = {
    getName: function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    getModel: function(){
        console.log(this.model);
    }
}

var bmw = new Automobile({
    name: 'BMW',
    model: 'm5'
})

Automobile.prototype = {
           sayHello:function(){
             console.log("Hello, I'm new");
        }
 }

// Make new Automobile

var honda = new Automobile({
    name: 'BMW',
    model: 'm5'
});

// Try to call getName, getModel
bmw.getName(); // BMW
bmw.getModel();  // m5

honda.getName(); // TypeError : undefined is not function
honda.getModel(); // TypeError : undefined is not function

// Try to call sayHello

bmw.sayHello(); // TypeError : undefined is not function

honda.sayHello(); // Hello, I'm new
```

Why bmw can't call sayHello and honda can't call getName and getModel ? 
Because i changed the prototype reference of Automobile after create bmw object.
bmw hold the reference to "old" prototype that contain getName, getModel but not sayHello . And honda hold the reference to "new" prototype that contain sayHello but not getName and getModel.

Hope it'll help you.